# Pattern matching sql algorithm

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table 1
Account ID   Account name 
Missing      Agreete NV.


Table 2 
Account ID   Account name 
XXX4546778   Agreete
```

I have to pouplate all the Account IDs in Table 1 based on the best match looking at the account name in both tables .

I thought about like, patindex & soundex.

Thinking about it I was thinking compare full string, if no match then compare full string -1 , if not match then then compare full string -2 until you get a match.

However someone must have came up with Pattern matching sql algorithm that will do this with a low error rate . Any ideas ?

Comment: a good one of these makes the owner alot of money :)

Comment: james, this is a great question, i am eager to see possible solutions for this

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps im missing the point of your question but it seems to me you have the exact match like you said

```
update t1
set [account id] = t2.[account id]
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.[account name] = t2.[account name]
where t1.[account id] = 'missing'
```

And you have the partial match

```
update t1
set [account id] = t2.[account id]
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.[account name] like t2.[account name] + '%'
where t1.[account id] = 'missing'
```

run in that order...